# External HDD shows up in dmesg but not in fdisk

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, fdisk, dmesg

I have an hdd with important data inside and I can't get it mounted to access the data. When connected I can hear it spin.

**dmesg:**

```
[11868.068196] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[11868.089062] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[11868.089066] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[11868.089068] usb 2-2: Product: AS2105
[11868.089071] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[11868.089073] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[11868.112789] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11868.112879] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[11868.112915] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[11868.113452] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[11868.115085] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[11890.496418] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

**lsusb:**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5d7 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**"fdisk -l":** only returns my pc's ssd.

I tried an hdd docking station (self powered) and a 2.5 case (not self powered), both of them work with other hdds but not on this one.I also tried changing usb port with no success. Tested with Ubuntu and Windows 10, on windows I can see the hdd in "device manager" but not in "disk manager". Pls halp.

Comment: You may try data recovery software but there's no guarantee it will work. The HDD may have a corrupt partition table and other errors.

Comment: Do you know how your HDD has been formatted?

Comment: @MichaelBay  can you name me a recovery software that works on hdd not detected on fdisk or gparted?

Comment: @muclux I know it had Windows on.

Comment: There are several free and commercial softwares for Windows. In Ubuntu most people start with Testdisk/Photorec. Also professional services usually very expensive. But AU isn't the place for  either recommendation. If you're using software running in Ubuntu you may ask a question about it if you need help, but please read and try following the instructions of whichever software you choose.

Comment: @MichaelBay thing is these softwares need the hdd to be detected somehow, testdisk and photorec just return "No harddisk found"